# Mulesoft S3 connector with AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, mulesoft

I am planning to use Mulesoft API S3 connector to integrate with AWS and I have a few queries.

1. Will the connector move the data via internet or other channel?
2. Is the data encrypted in transit?

Answer (score 0):

1. Will the connector move the data via internet or other channel?

The [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/amazon-s3-connector/5.6/#prerequisites) states that:

> ...you must have access to the Amazon S3 target resource, Amazon Web
> Services, and Anypoint Platform.

Basically the connector uses AWS SDK to connect to AWS S3 services, which uses HTTP REST APIs. The application has to have access to connect to S3 over the Internet because it will assume access to the public DNS hosts names for AWS.

2. Is the data encrypted in transit?

You can use an AWS KWS master key to [encrypt objects](https://docs.mulesoft.com/amazon-s3-connector/5.6/amazon-s3-connector-config-topics#use-an-aws-kms-master-key). Check with AWS documentation what that provides in term of encryption.